# Embeddable text are where users can insert the html

Tags: html, textarea

Is there a way to have a text area which allows html where users can paste their html code?

Comment: Paste their html codes for what? Explain what is your aim

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, but it's a ripe target for a [Cross-Site Scripting](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-A1) attack, which is a serious and widespread security problem.

If you're going to be a web programmer you must study security resources, for instance:

- [Open Web Application Security Project](http://owasp.org)
- SANS report on the [top 25 most dangerous programming errors](http://www.sans.org/top25-programming-errors/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can, the TEXTAREA element in HTML will not limit what text is placed within it.

So with simple html like below, your users would automatically be able to add HTML within.

```
<html>
<body>

<textarea rows="10" cols="30">
Any text can be placed inside a TEXTAREA element.
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

A couple of things to note:

1. You need to ensure you don't output what they put in to your website without encoding or parsing the data, they could hack your website otherwise, see [Cross Site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-A1)
2. You might want to consider using a WYSWIG editor like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) have a look at their [full example](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) but this really depends on what purpose you are wanting to use it for.

Good luck.